# How do I change the background on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, wallpaper

I can't you change the background on Linux. I can only use the images that are already installed on Linux, and if I try to set an image that I downloaded from the internet as a wallpaper, the screen will turn black. When I try to add a new image to the wallpaper option, I can't find my images, even though I have it on the download file.This is the setting that I see, and if I click "Add Picture," it does not show the picture that I have downloaded [image]

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you click on *Add Pictures*? 
You most likely wont see your downloaded picture, but will have to got to the downloads directory or where you put the image.

The Image might also not be in the right format or size for Ubuntu to show it so check that too.